# Android ADK with Arduino Uno - returns non-zero @ dispatchPkt in usb.cpp of ADK

Tags: arduino

I got `rcode` to be `4` at this line in newIntransfer():

```
rcode = dispatchPkt(tokIN, ep, nak_limit)
```

What may be the error?

I am connecting a Huawei y200t 4.03 with a [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and [ITead USB](http://www.simplelabs.co.in/content/itead-usb-host-shield-arduino) [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields). I am not connecting any external supply.

Comment: Got it.., I really messed up with usb libraries over net. Finally i compiled with [usbhostshield2.0](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) from felis at github and it works well on my arduino... please use this library for itead usb shield.

Comment: Post it as a separate answer and select it, so that this question doesn't show in unanswered questions.